# A required element cannot follow an optional element

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a typescript `type` that is basically an array with the following possibilities:

- `[ "name" ]` or
- `[ true, "name" ]`

The order here is **very important**. The `string` is *required*, but the `boolean` is *optional* and **must be the first argument**, when applicable.

But when I declare it as the [following code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/pt/play?ts=4.2.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAQg9nANhAhgOwIJoCYGVgBOAlmgOZQC8UA2lAEYLLoD8ANFAM6EnkC6A3ACggA):

```js
type BooleanAndString = [ boolean?, string ];
```

It shows: *a required element cannot follow an optional element (1257)*.

It could be workarounded with the [following code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/pt/play?ts=4.2.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAQg9nANhAhgOwIJoCYGVgBOAlmgOZQC8UA2lAEYLLoA0UAzoSeQLpQA%20AKCjCRoseJG0OxMlG4BuAQIDGcNByjAIHAIwAuWI1SYc%20GeSq0A5AFc2EAlbmLV64Ju3AATAfhJjWHicspaaBDYQrLb2js5AA):

```
type BooleanAndString = [ boolean, string ] |
                        [ string ];
```

But it makes the code a bit more complex, once that it is a very simplified case of what I need. And I want to use it as a tuple that comes from a JSON array in that order.

Just to make my problem clear, the [following structure](https://tsplay.dev/mplGMm) is one of the complex that I have, but I run to the same issue:

```js
type Message = [
    visible?: boolean,
    relatedField?: string,
    level: 's' | 'w' | 'i' | 'e' | 'd' | 'c',
    displayLevelDefaultTitle?: boolean,
    message: string,
    mergeable?: boolean
];
```

Comment: One solution is to make **ALL** of the elements optional. For overload resolution, the optional elements _MUST_ be last, this is a restriction that we've had to adhere to forever, don't try to fight it. Otherwise please provide more information on why your _FIRST_ element _MUST_ be optional, there might be a different solution to that requirement that we can help with.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller even if all elements are optional, I keep having a problem. For instance: `type X = [ boolean?, string? ]` can't be used like `[ "test" ]` (*type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean | undefined'*).

Comment: @ChrisSchaller I have a very defined elements ordering with some optionals. For instance, imagine that `[ big?: boolean, message: string, closeable?: boolean ]` is possible. So I can setup a message big and keep closeable as default (`[ true, "hello" ]`) or a normal message not closeable (`[ "hello", false ]`). But if I am forced to push `message` to first position, I will have `[ message: string, big?: boolean, closeable?: boolean ]`. So if I need create a normal message not closeable, I must specify entire routing like `[ "test", null, false ]`.

Comment: Your "following structure" link is broken.  Also, could you provide a [mcve] with how you consume such a list of arguments with such non-final optional elements?  Are you checking `arguments.length` or something?

Comment: @jcalz In fact, I had thought that Typescript would be able to do this kind of "alignment" automatically. But from what I'm [reading here](https://dirask.com/posts/TypeScript-constructor-overloads-multiple-constructors-many-constructors-xpJ471), it looks like I have to do this manually. Maybe some package can help me. (The broken link appears to be a limitation of Typescript Playground with large scripts.)

Comment: I've posted some links to quite large scripts myself; it's more likely the broken link is something wrong with your copy of the link; could you try to fix it?  Or, let me look at it... okay, you've got lots of `%20` in there which is not valid.  If I change them to `+`, then I get [this](https://tsplay.dev/mplGMm).

Comment: Yeah, this is not really done for you automatically; TypeScript compiles to JavaScript, which doesn't have type annotations.  If you want some behavior to happen at runtime, you need to write that yourself.  Even if I come up with something that programmatically generates an appropriate union-of-tuple type, it would really only be useful for the *caller*.  The consumer of that thing needs to jump through hoops to figure out where the parameters are, and you'd likely have to use type assertions to convince the compiler that you have it right.  Are you *sure* you want this?

Answer (score 1):

Prologue: I really recommend refactoring so that your code works *with* TypeScript instead of against it.  That would mean all your [optional parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#optional-parameters) should be moved to the end, and if you want to skip one optional parameter and pass a later one, you need to explicitly send `undefined`.  Meaning, if you have `(p2: 2, p1?: 1, p3?: 3)=>void`, you call `f(2)`, `f(2,1)`, `f(2,1,3)`, or `f(2,undefined,3)`.

Note that doing this enables your function implementation to be sane, since every parameter will be at a known index, and you can just check that index for a value of `undefined`. Without this, you'll find that it is quite complicated to figure out where your parameters actually are.  (Sometimes it's even *impossible*, since some orderings/typings of parameters are ambiguous like `[surname?: string, occupation?: string]` where `["Baker"]` could refer to the tailor named Jane Baker or the baker named Jane Tailor.)  It is this sanity of implementation that drives TypeScript's rule about allowable locations for optional parameters.

Or, even better, you could just make a single argument of an object type, and don't worry about parameter order.  Forget about labeled tuples, and use actual object keys.  So you'd have `(arg: {p1?: 1, p2: 2, p3?: 3})=>void` and call `f({p2: 2})`, `f({p2: 2, p1: 1})`, `f({p2: 2, p1: 1, p3: 3})`, or `f({p2: 2, p3: 3})`.  Yes, it's a bit more verbose, but it doesn't require the caller to have to remember some frankly arbitrary parameter order.  And this is even easier for the implementation to consume, since you just use named keys instead of numbered indices.

Okay, from here on out, let's assume that you can't refactor, and you have your own way of parsing the function parameters to pull the right values out of the right places... meaning that such concerns are outside the scope of this question.  Onward:

---

Your workaround of

```
type BooleanAndString = [ boolean, string ] | [ string ];
```

is probably the only reasonable way forward.  If your problem is that you don't want to do this *manually* for something like `Message`, it is possible to use [recursive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) along with [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) and a sprinkle of [labeled tuple elements](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#labeled-tuple-elements) to make this happen *programmatically*.

First, since you can't use the `?` optional marker yourself, let's define a stand-in for it:

```
type OptionalMarker<T> = { __optional: T };
```

Then, we will take your `Message` definition and change it to use `OptionalMarker` instead of `?`.  And we'll rename it to something else so that `Message` can be the output of our transformation:

```
type MessageMarker = [
    visible: OptionalMarker<boolean>,
    relatedField: OptionalMarker<string>,
    level: Level,
    displayLevelDefaultTitle: OptionalMarker<boolean>,
    message: string,
    mergeable: OptionalMarker<boolean>
];

type Level = 's' | 'w' | 'i' | 'e' | 'd' | 'c'
```

Oh, and I've created the `Level` type alias so that IntelliSense doesn't keep repeating `'s' | 'w' |` ... all over the place later.

Now we will define `Optionalize<T>`, which turns something like `MessageMarker` to a union of tuples with the optional elements either present or absent in the expected places.

```
type Optionalize<T extends any[]> = T extends [infer F, ...infer R] ?
    [...[F] extends [OptionalMarker<infer U>] ?
        LabeledSingleton<T, U> | [] : LabeledSingleton<T>, ...Optionalize<R>] : []

type LabeledSingleton<T extends any[], V = T[0]> = T extends [x: any, ...args: infer R] ?
    T extends [...infer L, ...R] ? { [K in keyof L]: V } : never : never;
```

Here, `Optionalize<T>` checks each element of `T` for whether or not it's `OptionalMarker<U>` for some `U`.  If so, you include-or-exclude `U`.  If not, you include the element without changing it.

The business with `LabeledSingleton<T, V>` is a way to take a tuple type with labels like `[foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3]` and return a single-element tuple whose label is that same as the first label from `T`, and whose value type is `V`.  So `LabeledSingleton<[foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3], string>` will be `[foo: string]`.  This lets me preserve your labels from `Message` in what follows.

---

Let's try it out:

```
type Message = Optionalize<MessageMarker>;
```

IntelliSense, if it did not truncate things, would give you this:

```
/* type Message = 
  [level: Level, message: string] | 
  [level: Level, message: string, mergeable: boolean] | 
  [level: Level, displayLevelDefaultTitle: boolean, message: string] | 
  [level: Level, displayLevelDefaultTitle: boolean, message: string, mergeable: boolean] |
  [relatedField: string, level: Level, message: string] | 
  [relatedField: string, level: Level, message: string, mergeable: boolean] | 
  [relatedField: string, level: Level, displayLevelDefaultTitle: boolean, message: string] | 
  [relatedField: string, level: Level, displayLevelDefaultTitle: boolean, message: string, mergeable: boolean] | 
  [visible: boolean, level: Level, message: string] | 
  [visible: boolean, level: Level, message: string, mergeable: boolean] | 
  [visible: boolean, level: Level, displayLevelDefaultTitle: boolean, message: string] | 
  [visible: boolean, level: Level, displayLevelDefaultTitle: boolean, message: string, mergeable: boolean]
  [visible: boolean, relatedField: string, level: Level, message: string] | 
  [visible: boolean, relatedField: string, level: Level, message: string, mergeable: boolean] | 
  [visible: boolean, relatedField: string, level: Level, displayLevelDefaultTitle: boolean, message: string] | 
  [visible: boolean, relatedField: string, level: Level, displayLevelDefaultTitle: boolean, message: string, mergeable: boolean]
*/
```

As you can see, it's a 16-member union that you didn't have to write out manually.  And now your example code all works as expected.  Furthermore, [assignment narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments) allows the compiler to know which of the 16 members you are using for any given value:

```
const simpleMessage: Message = ["s", "user saved"];
// Success: user saved.
// const simpleMessage: [level: Level, message: string]

const hiddenMessage: Message = [false, "i", "CPU usage for this operation: 0.1%"];
// <hidden> Information: CPU usage for this operation: 0.1%.
// const hiddenMessage: [visible: boolean, level: Level, message: string]
```

Hooray, I guess!

---

Epilogue: so, you can jump through a bunch of type-juggling hoops and convert something like the tuple you *want* to write into the union-of-tuples you *can* write.  And after that, you still have to deal with the function implementation.  If you do decide to go down this route, I don't envy you.  Even though such a thing is sort of possible, it doesn't seem to be a use case that TypeScript is meant to support.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#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-JMp42rI610MFijmPTlBzuCeRpd-uOqNulBT-OznVwSeiHcHlx3rsUNeoFvI9D3aLF+iUQZhgfDAJmmOYFiWFYoF-FIPzPR5L0aACgPaEDH3AyCRiPWDZnmRZlkeFCUDQl8LzfS4n0-XZv2QxIPmvXdsiGPJCmKDBSjoi4nCxO88OPRj0NfITsN8TwuNyfIihKKT3ygUTOlAiTaMw4TGNuZikKomSqXknilP4lSGPU6CwIGIYiPGKZSIQiifzYv8aPHSynGMuScjMviBJ0kTgI0-C7Kg4inPg8jDPc1CtK8wTVJuL84p2FJfICIIWKokLcLC8TnySnSssCEJ0o+fKD0Kzzz2CvS0so+L-2rXdsoq5qMuotTQpsvoIoc2QSJixCuqqxL6vony2tkjrcpa6r7yPWyIPs6CRrIsa3O6uqMOmj99PuSq-y+dryoW3aoFMxTAu8paxL27yypyk6Epu3jlOSqy+pWyb9qEw6mp29jZqpea3p6j7zKCg7eoK-qCPWqK4K21zWKu4qpuksHPAh8aPOu-zbq+hrrL+pHIsc1GXMhp7vt01KDIJzLBFXZdhEEcxUFqC8EAOQZXGOJKtxcLwACIlHFrFxZmJQPEcGQTHFn4V2XKAQRmcxzGOLg5YVtAlfpNWoG5lBeaCAWwlFx491+zSsYBq9hDN3mAAsEBMEwRRtrgba8aYMHlmWEGlqBxYAYQABQzKA5e3SYkFNYAPZRFgiFyNguAJekAEYAFIVaEZd1eID2vZFSgAEkQyTg5M9QLho9j+OxcT5PU6gdPcAblBs7z-PjZL02eeAKBy+9lBffBi66fhmr+sd56XdHonuPyaf-ZoTxxYgeuEAwMPd6Pve0AP1EveyBxVRRbIAEcZgQbJldV4fiA+jckFVFAwBmYBPHQEcKgu996H2JFAAAorgXAScuCn3PmgS+xwb5Ewfk-fIQ91auzHh9aefl16fQsgzB6tV-rLy5qvcwcsoQHGgpvYWYtt6SzDoHYO4d9amk0GgFEit8hQE0EsN2F4tY6wcEXE2GZ5acO4ReQ2fCBEp2EdrY49IoAAAoABySA8gbjdrkVUY8TBIHsOabRqIwCDGKCiFO0BJYiOOOLZCUwk4QHpAASjVtg021CkC0KPHg8mmlKZDRgtFNGc8l4MzOhQ82Y8mYmHoehDEXgd5Sxlhw2RSsVYZB3qHGWZtJhP3rmsDWWAQT8JkfLFAwBsmCFyUfApRTe6wlARUnhIoalfFfurTWyiHB6ykZkjBJsa7t2KVnE2UAAC0UAI6oEKbgcZqBSnlK4e06pxd1bTNmfMppJT4FyDWReDpvwvEzBQPExJ85knb1SUfDJvCX45PFnk8OjTFnNJBGUtpxzqksMwPLTEdSXkNN2R8-ZrSjlVJqViVhEAulCF6MPXpojWRx0GY842SL1ajLrr3Lg7ylkoBWT86FiK-DD1xeCrOI8Qx7LYC0s+hzKknIFMPTR2joAp30SgJAmgsTsjxWsFEeBoDBL4fLMAeAFImAwCAdxwggA)

Comment: I am very grateful for all of your explanation and, although I will take the time to understand exactly how it works, it looks like it is not going to solve what I would really like to solve. The type itself will work, but I will not be able to extract the information as I could for an object (eg. `message.level`), which was what I expected. But it seems that tuples don't work well that way. I will rethink about this model to check what I can do now. Thank you, in any case, for your time invested in this problem. Thank you very much!